# How to I use SemaphoreSlim or Dataflow to handle notification throttling?

Tags: c#, parallel-processing, taskscheduler

I have a situation where our application receives notifications when information is updated.  When we receives a notification, we will fetch the latest change in async fashion in a WPF application.  What I like to do is when a flood of notification comes, it will accumulate and be throttled.

So if there were 10 notifications send to the client, the system will wait 5 seconds and call an async method to refresh.  Every 5 seconds, it will request for latest changes 1 instead of requesting 10 times for changes.

Can someone **guide me with an example** on the **best way** to handle it?

Comment: If only one notification is received by the client, it should still wait for 5 seconds before refreshing?

Comment: yes.  it will wait 5 seconds before refreshing as notifications comes very rapidly.

Comment: Throttling of what? _Receiving_ the notification or _displaying_? I'm guessing displaying (as in Windows Action Centre popups).  Any code to show? [mcve]

Comment: throttling of handling of notification.  so for example, every 5 seconds, we cound get x number of notications.  Regarless how many notifications, I will only need make a request to get latest changes once.  And in another 5 seconds, i could get 100 notifications that something has changed, I will still only make 1 request to get latest changes on the server side.  Thank you.

Comment: So basically you are saying you want to process incoming notifications every 5 seconds, where there could be anything from 0 to 100s of notifications waiting.  Regardless of scenario, you perform a single check to get the latest.  It sounds to me you are `already` doing _"throttling"_.

Comment: yes.  I am using LimitedConcurrencyLevelTaskScheduler  from https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.threading.tasks.taskscheduler?view=netframework-4.8 where I queue up notifications and delays processing by 5 seconds.  But I read that TaskScheduler is best for CPU intensive processing.  and using semaphoreslim or dataflow is a better way to go but needs some help to how it could be done.  Thanks.

Comment: There's no need to use that

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could use a [`DispatcherTimer`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.windows.threading.dispatchertimer) with 5 seconds `Interval`. Start the timer whenever you receive a notification, provided that it's not already started. In the `Tick` event handler stop the timer and refresh the displayed data.